# Interpreting DMARC report

Tags: spf, dkim, google, dmarc, report

I have DKIM and SPF configured for my SMTP server, and recently set
the policies to strict/reject.  I received the report shown below from
Google. Ths source IP is not my SMTP server.

I read this as Google checking DKIM and SPF, with both failing, and
then rejecting 17 messages; i.e. the desired result.

Is this the correct interpretation?

```
  ...
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>159.253.0.54</source_ip>
      <count>17</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>reject</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>[obfuscated]</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <spf>
        <domain>[obfuscated]</domain>
        <result>fail</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 17 emails from 159.253.0.54 marked as rejected by google.

Doug isn't wrong, but the direct link is https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-xml/ which will give you similar output.

I don't know if you specified strict alignment for either spf or dkim or both, but since both failed they will follow reject.

Comment: I specified strict for both, and it looks like it's working.  Score one tiny anti-SPAM victory!